# use py installer with pyqt but I get an error

Tags: python, pyqt, pyinstaller, importerror

Currently, I am working on a login form with PyQt and Python. I want to convert my python file into a .exe with pyinstaller but it is not working as aspected.

In total, I have three python files. The first file is my main Python file and the other two are Python files with all PyQt stuff.

main.py

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QDialog, QApplication
from PyQt5.uic import loadUi
from test import Login_Ui_Dialog
from createacc import Create_Ui_Dialog

class Login(QDialog):

    def __init__(self):
        super(Login, self).__init__()
        self.ui_d = Login_Ui_Dialog()
        self.ui_d.setupUi(self)
        self.ui_d.loginbutton.clicked.connect(self.loginfunction)
        self.ui_d.password.setEchoMode(QtWidgets.QLineEdit.Password)
        self.ui_d.createaccbutton.clicked.connect(self.gotocreate)
    .
    .
    .

class CreateAcc(QDialog):
    def __init__(self):
        super(CreateAcc, self).__init__()
        self.ui_c = Create_Ui_Dialog()
        self.ui_c.setupUi(self)
        self.ui_c.signupbutton.clicked.connect(self.createaccfunction)
        self.ui_c.password.setEchoMode(QtWidgets.QLineEdit.Password)
        self.ui_c.confirmpass.setEchoMode(QtWidgets.QLineEdit.Password)
   .
   .
   .
```

test.py

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets


class Login_Ui_Dialog(object):
    def setupUi(self, Dialog):
        Dialog.setObjectName("Dialog")
     .
     .
     .
```

createacc.py

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets


class Create_Ui_Dialog(object):
    def setupUi(self, Dialog):
        Dialog.setObjectName("Dialog")

    .
    .
    .
```

Now if I want to create my main file to an executable file with pyinstaller,

> pyinstaller --onefile main.py

I got an error if I execute the main.exe

> File "main.py", line 5, in  ImportError: cannot import name
> 'Login_Ui_Dialog' from 'test'
> (C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp_MEI128682\test_*init*_.pyc)
> [15888] Failed to execute script main

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: you didt put much information here, this question is just me try to understand : is the test file in the same folder, and are you using ui file or convert it to an py file

Comment: yeah, all files are in the same folder. After a long time of testing, I got it working yesterday.